Inactivity monitor on HTTP transport is creating lots of clutter and failures
We are using ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.x. We're also using Camel 4.0.0 with the ActiveMQ component configured with the HTTP transport (because we are forced to based on the networks involved).
The traffic is very spikey in our app which means we have to keep a lot of connections in the pool to deal with those spikes. The broker is "distant" network-wise and creating a new network connection takes multiple seconds.
However, we get a constant stream of failed puts due to timed-out connections (30 seconds).
I can't figure out how to deactivate the inactivity monitor with this transport. The wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration and transport.useInactivityMonitor parms on the connection string get rejected which fails the connection.
2024-04-19 15:13:36,717 ERROR [prm.rte.PutJMSRslt] (Camel (PrimeQueryContext) thread #261 - JmsConsumer[-queuename-])  PersonSubject Handler fails writing to -queuename for xxx/P1068EAB29ED8FQ000064289 due to: org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: Channel was inactive (no connection attempt made) for too (>30000) long: https://xxx:443/message-queue
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:274)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:184)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:510)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:572)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:425)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:392)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:159)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:172)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:383)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$PipelineTask.run(Pipeline.java:102)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.executeReactiveWork(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:196)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:164)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:163)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:383)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:32)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:132)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:330)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:269)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1239)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1229)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: jakarta.jms.IllegalStateException: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: Channel was inactive (no connection attempt made) for too (>30000) long: https://xxx:443/message-queue
        at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:196)
        at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnection.createSession(JmsPoolConnection.java:194)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:213)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:498)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: Channel was inactive (no connection attempt made) for too (>30000) long: https://xxx:443/message-queue
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.checkClosedOrFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:1518)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:369)
        at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.pool.PooledConnection.makeSession(PooledConnection.java:148)
        at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.pool.PooledConnection$1.makeObject(PooledConnection.java:107)
        at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.pool.PooledConnection$1.makeObject(PooledConnection.java:102)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:780)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:439)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:350)
        at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:178)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive (no connection attempt made) for too (>30000) long: https://xxx:443/message-queue
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor$1$1.run(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:96)
        ... 3 more


Client gets these errors when performing a "PUT", which appears to fail the attempt.
Yes, creating new network connections takes multiple seconds. A normal PUT takes in the 200-300 milli range.  New connections are 2-4 seconds.
The HTTP client. Or put differently, the connect string we use starts with "http"

Wouldn't help.  This is an apache Camel application, using the AMQ "component" provided. This isn't a "code" problem.

yes, that is a built-in component of camel
V4.0.0

Based on the stack-trace there's nothing related to a "PUT". In fact, that's not even part of the JMS API which Camel is using here. The problem is when a Connection is fetched from the pool and createSession is invoked on it. However, the connection has been closed to the call fails. Can you elaborate on where you see a "PUT"?

Using the spring jms template, a put triggers a call for a new connection and session, which must succeed before the PUT is actually initiated. Of course, it is making these calls to the connection pool, so reusing previously created connections.

Does this answer your question? ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor params not applied on HTTP Transport connection

So, ended up being really simple. The only documented ways I could find to defeat the inactivity monitor were documented for other transports, and included a prefix to isolate them to the relevant layer of that stack.
For the HTTP client, the property itself can be used without prefix. Thus:
useInactivityMonitor=false
I never thought to try that, but it does work, so I've been able to suppress the disruptive connection shutdowns.

The HTTP transport does not support the maxInactivityDuration setting - that is specific to the OpenWire protocol, while the HTTP transport uses the xstream protocol (see org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory#getDefaultWireFormatType).
For wide area connections, the best practice is to use an active HTTP gateway in front of ActiveMQ instead of having clients directly connect to the broker over the wide area network.  HTTP has far richer tooling for short-lived connections over less reliable networks, as well as load-balancing, proxying,
offloaded SSL termination, etc.  JMS relies on long-lived connections and suffers when connections are unreliable.
Another consideration is the lack of good protection from anti-patterns inside the broker.  One bad actor connected to the broker can easily lead to significant problems for the entire broker, and tracking down that bad actor can be challenging.  An active HTTP gateway gives a natural place to add controls and checks to prevent JMS anti-patterns (such as slow consumption and oversized transactions).
By "active", I am referring to an HTTP service that sits between the broker and cross-wan clients.  Nginx does not meet that definition.
There are other reasons using HTTP with the broker itself is not ideal.
Hope this helps.

This connection does go through an nginex gateway. We have no control over that config.
So, I really need to find a way to tell the local transport agent NOT to run the inactivity monitoring, since that's the only part of this I can influence.  It may not help, if the other end of the connection is causing the problem.  But, trying home in on the culprit.

If you want to change the inactivity monitoring with the AMQ http transport implemenation, a code change will be needed.  Note that I don't know of anyone that uses that transport - I suspect it does not get a high level of attention.  Note too that putting -1 on the answer doesn't change the underlying facts.  I'm just trying to help you find a path to success - AMQ doesn't do everything that everybody wants perfectly, but it does do some things really well....

I don't know where the -1 came from.  Not me.

Ahh, apologies for the assumption.  Anyway, I hope the feedback helps.
